# Reading data from s3 subdirectories in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, aws-glue, pyspark

I want to read all parquet files from an S3 bucket, including all those in the subdirectories (these are actually prefixes).

Using wildcards (*) in the S3 url only works for the files in the specified folder. For example using this code will only read the parquet files below the `target/` folder.

```
df = spark.read.parquet("s3://bucket/target/*.parquet")
df.show()
```

Let say i have a structure like this in my s3 bucket:

```
"s3://bucket/target/2020/01/01/some-file.parquet"
"s3://bucket/target/2020/01/02/some-file.parquet"
```

The above code will raise the exception:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Path does not exist: s3://mailswitch-extract-underwr-prod/target/*.parquet;'
```

**How can I read all the parquet files from the subdirectories from my s3 bucket?**

To run my code, I am using AWS Glue 2.0 with Spark 2.4 and python 3.

Comment: you only need a `basePath` when you're providing a list of specific files within that path. @Surya Shekhar Chakraborty answer is what you need.

Comment: Thanks. while digging down this issue. it looks more to be a problem of reading s3 "sub directories" and using wildcards. I updated the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to read all parquet files below the target folder

```
"s3://bucket/target/2020/01/01/some-file.parquet"
"s3://bucket/target/2020/01/02/some-file.parquet"
```

you can do

```
df = spark.read.parquet("bucket/target/*/*/*/*.parquet")
```

The downside is that you need to know the depth of your parquet files.

Answer (score 1):

For those like me in search of an answer for "How can I read all the files in my s3 bucket using PySpark?", the answer (following OP's example) simply is

```
df = spark.read.parquet("s3://bucket/target/")
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
df = spark.read.parquet("s3://your/path/here/some*wildcard")
```

Comment: While investigating this i found out this only works for files right below the here/ folder. but for files in subdirectories this doesn't work. i'll update my original question